# How to center raw js in WP's virtual composer?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm using Virtual Composer and insert a raw js element. Then I paste the  code within the element - it all works great!

But I'd like the output script to be centered on my page. Right now it automatically aligns to the left.

The script is displaying a scrolling banner with 4 items. If I put edit the "raw js" element, and put the script between , the banners themselves don't show up…but if I mouse over where they would be, I can see the left/right navigation arrows - and those are centered - but not much good without the banners themselves ;)

Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps did you mean **Visual** Composer?
So in this case you can try insert simple text box, switch from visual to text mode(html) and do some html/js

Comment: Hey! Yes, that's what I meant ;) And I should've thought of that…but haven't been editing in a while…so, I tried it, and nothing displayed. But I'm pretty sure you're on the right track and now that you've shaken my brain loose a bit, I think it will just take a little trial and error - going to work on that now and then I'll put the appended answer here and check it off as your answer being correct - because I'm pretty sure it is, just my site is overflowing with plugins and I think that's an issue. Thanks!

Comment: Can't get it quite to work…this is the code, from the text editor, I'm trying to center `[vc_raw_js]JTNDc2NyaXB0JTIwdHlwZSUzRCUyN3RleHQlMkZqYXZhc2NyaXB0JTI3JTIwc3JjJTNEJTI3aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZmZWVkLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20lMkZGZWVkU3RvcmUlMkZHZXRGZWVkLmFzaHglM0ZGZWVkR3JvdXBJZCUzRGU5MTFiNDcyLWMzNTQtNGU4MC04ZTJlLWQyOWM0NjNhMGViMSUybGl2ZS5jb20lMjZFbWFpbElEJTNEaW5mbyUyNTQwdGVjaG5vbG9neXNvbHV0aW9uc2xpdmUuY29tJTI2SW50ZXJ2YWwlM0Q3MDAwJTI2d2lkdGglM0Q2MDBweCUyNmhlaWdodCUzRDI1MHB4JTI3JTNFJTNDJTJGc2NyaXB0JTNF[/vc_raw_js]`